When I used Flutter for the first time in a while, I encountered an error in 'analysis_options.yaml' and was unable to resolve it
In the analysis_options.yaml file, the part
include: package:very_good_analysis/analysis_options.yaml

causes the following error:
Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?dart(parse_error)
The colon is correctly written.
I referred to this question, but it didn't solve the problem:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/49946
How can I resolve this error?
Switching the Dart and Flutter extensions to the pre-release versions did not resolve the error.

This question is similar to: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is a question about the analysis_options.yaml file.
Also, as you wrote in the question, my indentation is fine and I never had this error before.

The error message suggests the problem has to do with the content of the yaml file. Maybe include the complete analysis_options.yaml file?
